# Circular Dependancy Issue

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

I've been writing an NES emulator this summer and I've ran into a roadblock.  I'm trying to test my ppu code, but I can't get my code to compile because of a circular dependency.

What I currently have:

- Three classes: cpu, ppu and memory
- headers: cpu.h, ppu.h and memory.h
- cpp files: cpu.cpp, ppu.cpp, memory.cpp and main.cpp

The dependency issue is in memory.h.  Currently, ppu.h includes memory.h so that I can access VRAM, and memory.h includes ppu.h so that I can update flags or addresses in VRAM depending on what the cpu writes to memory.  I've tried a forward declaration of the ppu class since I only use a ppu pointer, but this failed.

Here is what happens with an example piece of my code with a forward declaration:

```
case 0x2000:
ppu->ppuTempAddress |= ((data & 0x03) << 10);
break;
```

And the error:

```
In file included from memory.cpp:1:0:
memory.h:7:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class ppu’
memory.cpp:99:10: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class ppu’
```

include "ppu.h" outputs this error (which doesn't occur without the include):

```
In file included from memory.h:6:0,
                 from memory.cpp:1:
ppu.h:13:20: error: ‘memory’ has not been declared
ppu.h:63:25: error: ‘memory’ has not been declared
ppu.h:66:29: error: ‘memory’ has not been declared
```

Any suggestions on what to do from here?  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2):

You should include ppu.h in memory.cpp (after memory.h), not inside memory.h, as memory.h only needs the forward declaration and the error occurs in memory.cpp

Forward declarations can only be used to declare pointers and references, but to actually use those references you need the full class definition. As the usage should only occur in the .cpp file, the headers of the forward declared classes should be included there. The only case where you do not need the header at all is if you only pass around pointers to objects of the foward declared class without actually accessing the pointed-to objects.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That fixed the problem. I do have one more question for you if you don't mind.  When I forward declare a class, should I always include the header of the class in the .cpp file?  Or is this just an isolated incident?

Comment: @SeanK added something about that

Answer (score 0):

Such a problem comes from using a type that is forward declared, when the compiler has not seen the full declaration. Forward declaration is just telling the compiler "this type exists".

While you do not show complete code, I suspect that you have executable code in your header files. Take it out and put *all* executable code in your .cpp files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inline things:

```
A.h
  #ifndef A_H
  #define A_H
  class A {};
  #include "A.hcc"
  #endif

A.hcc
  #ifndef A_H
  #error Please include A.h, instead.
  #endif
  #include "B.h"
  // inline functions 
  ...

B.h
  #ifndef B_H
  #define B_H
  class B {};
  #include "B.hcc"
  #endif

B.hcc
  #ifndef B_H
  #error Please include B.h, instead.
  #endif
  #include "A.h"
  // inline functions 
  ...
```

Comment: I don't get this answer... Can you give a more elaborate example?

Comment: @Skalli Look at it: A.h includes A.hcc, which includes B.h, which includes B.hcc, which likes to include the already guarded A.h. The effect is: B is fully declared and all B inline functions are visible to A.hcc. A is fully declared, but the inline functions of A are invisible for B.hcc. In any other file including A.h or B.h the inline functions of A.hcc and B.hcc are visible.

Comment: Then it's not making sense to me why aou are doing it this way instead of just declaring a prototype in a header file, include it and put the definition in a source file and let the linker do the work. The example seems overly complex to me, also an unneccessary compile time overhead. Positive side effects would be a faster compile time with the same runtime behaviour. Correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Skalli Circular dependence: Have A utilize the inline functions of B and vice versa.

Comment: That's why there are prototypes and forward declarations. _A.h_ would use the forward declaration `class B;` in _B.cpp_ you would include _A.h_ **after** _B.h_. Wouldn't that be a cleaner approach?

Comment: @Skalli The point is having an A inline function using a B inline function (and vice versa)

Comment: Then I'd rather move the function prototypes to a different header file `A_inline_functions.h`. Your approach slows down compile times alot. It's not very common to include a *.cpp file in a header file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35596/discussion-between-dieter-lucking-and-skalli)